# Integrating Google Docs - Authentication and Access

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm interested in integrating Google Docs with our application, and curious if the API will support our use case.

Our user would see a link on our site to open a document (document created programmatically). When they click the link, it would open up Google Docs (in another browser tab) in either write or read-only mode depending on permission in our system. Preferably the user wouldn't need a Google account at all. Also, before they click the link we would like to show a completely static HTML representation of a particular revision of that document. It would be also nice to listen to changes (from our back-end) to documents to update say the static html or some such. They wouldn't be able to create new documents, or delete the document.

In Summary:

- Control document create/deletion
- Control document sharing (some workaround may be acceptable here)
- Authenticate thru our service to edit/view doc
- Add comments to document thru API
- Turn document into static HTML

It might be nice to customize the Google Doc editor to make it more geared for the type documents we create (film scripts), but not required, a template is helpful, so creating a doc with a template would be nice.

Which API's, account types, etc do we need to accomplish the above if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google account is required to interact with Google Drive and Google Docs.  What you could do is, upon clicking, authorize access to the user's Google Drive account, copy a doc into their Drive, and then redirect them into editing the newly copied doc.  All of your other requirements are supported.

You can do these things with the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive).

Comment: So, they would need to sign up for a Google Drive account? There isn't a way around that?

Comment: Sorry no, Google Drive is an authenticated service.  It requires identity and a sense of ownership to function correctly.